# Query Azure Application Insights CustomEvents in Azure function in C#.Net

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, kql

I need to query CustomEvents under application insights in an azure function.

I was able to read CustomEvents using below package:
*Microsoft.Azure.ApplicationInsights.Query*

Here is the code:

```
            string applicationId = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx";
            string key = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

            // Create client
            var credentials = new ApiKeyClientCredentials(key);
            var applicationInsightsClient = new ApplicationInsightsDataClient(credentials);

            // Query Application Insights
            var query = "customEvents" +
                        " | where timestamp > ago(840h)" +
                        " | take 3";
            var response = await applicationInsightsClient.Query.ExecuteWithHttpMessagesAsync(applicationId, query);
```

The library 'Microsoft.Azure.ApplicationInsights.Query is however deprecated and suggestion is to use Azure.Monitor.Query

Below is the code that Microsoft documentation has as an example to query logs using Azure.Monitor.Query :

```
Azure.Response<Azure.Monitor.Query.Models.LogsQueryResult> response = await logsQueryClient.QueryWorkspaceAsync(
                "<workspaceId>",
                "customEvents ",
                new QueryTimeRange(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(300)));
```

Since this library queries using workspace id, I linked my application insights instance to a log analytics workspace instance. However the function fails with a BadArgumentError "Failed to resolve table or column expression named 'customEvents'"

Is there a way we can query CustomEvents using the package Azure.Monitor.Query?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works.
Below is a tested code.

Once you link your Application Insights to Azure Monitor workspace, you can query your AI tables from that WS, without the need to use [app()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/cross-workspace-query#identifying-an-application).
The thing is that the tables` names are different, e.g., *traces* becomes *AppTraces*.

In the same manner, ***customEvents*** becomes ***AppEvents***.

Well, it turns out it is even documented, under [Migrate to workspace-based Application Insights resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/convert-classic-resource#table-structure)

| Legacy table name | New table name | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| availabilityResults | AppAvailabilityResults | Summary data from availability tests. |
| browserTimings | AppBrowserTimings | Data about client performance, such as the time taken to process the incoming data. |
| dependencies | AppDependencies | Calls from the application to other components (including external components) recorded via TrackDependency() – for example, calls to REST API, database or a file system. |
| **customEvents** | **AppEvents** | Custom events created by your application. |
| customMetrics | AppMetrics | Custom metrics created by your application. |
| pageViews | AppPageViews | Data about each website view with browser information. |
| performanceCounters | AppPerformanceCounters | Performance measurements from the compute resources supporting the application, for example, Windows performance counters. |
| requests | AppRequests | Requests received by your application. For example, a separate request record is logged for each HTTP request that your web app receives. |
| exceptions | AppExceptions | Exceptions thrown by the application runtime, captures both server side and client-side (browsers) exceptions. |
| traces | AppTraces | Detailed logs (traces) emitted through application code/logging frameworks recorded via TrackTrace(). |

```
using Azure;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Monitor.Query;
using Azure.Monitor.Query.Models;

string workspaceId = "...";

var client = new LogsQueryClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());

try
{
    Response<LogsQueryResult> response = await client.QueryWorkspaceAsync(
        workspaceId,
        "AppEvents | count",
        QueryTimeRange.All);

    LogsTable table = response.Value.Table;

    foreach (var row in table.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(row);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to consider upvoting in addition for accepting the answer.